# How to access my own Gmail account by bypassing Google Security Checkup

Tags: selenium, security, gmail, browser-automation, google-settings

I have developed an automation software for verifying Google oAuth using Gmail account sign(configured my own 4 gmail accounts). It is actually working fine from my machine.

While automation runs from a remote machine(ran from jenkins with 3 hrs of interval) we are obtaining a pop up for 'verify its you'. :(.

Also I verified each configured account, I can see remote ip is listed on my "Devices & Activity" page as an Unknown Device and it keeps getting refused (in all configured gmail account).

At some point I clicked on this device as being okay, but it continues to get blocked

The message listed under it is `We recently prevented a sign-in attempt to this device. You indicated this attempt as yours. For your security, we'll continue to show this device in the list for two weeks. You can also review this event in your Notification & alerts page`.

How can I stop this from happening? If I go to the Notification and Alerts page, there is still no option to stop this.You can see in the message that I clearly indicated the attempt as mine, but Google continues to stop it.

I have tried following method , but didn't worked.

1. Less secure apps option in the gmail account
2. tried this url, https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
3. also tried resetting password for each configured account

Please help

Comment: What are you trying to achieve as a whole?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Trying to automate some scenarios around 'Google oAuth Sign-In in my web app'

Comment: Did you find any solution yet ?

Comment: @AmrLotfy No solutions obtained yet

Comment: @AnIshA check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52126066/1356559