# Automating gmail login [During oAuth] gets blocked with user verification

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver, gmail, selenium-chromedriver

This code works to login to gmail

```
public void login(User user) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    WebElement emailTextBox = wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("identifierId")));
    emailTextBox.sendKeys(user.email);

    WebElement nextButton = wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Next')]")));
    nextButton.click();

    WebElement passwordTextBox = wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")));
    passwordTextBox.sendKeys(user.password);

    nextButton = wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Next')]")));
    nextButton.click();
}
```

**Problem**

We have a web application under test where users can login with google (oAuth2), however gmail traps automation script with a user verification (reset password or captcha or phone number).

**Q:**

Is there any way to avoid gmail user verification ?

(I am not asking to solve google verification challenge, in normal browser run by user manually this verification challenge doesn't get triggered (most of times), but with selenium it sometimes happens and fails my tests.)

**Update 19.08.2018**

This is a dead end, bypassing google verification is not trivial, upon searching more I found that service virtualization is the correct way to solve this issue, possibly [Hoverfly](https://github.com/SpectoLabs/hoverfly-java).

Comment: What does the _user verification_ ask you to do? Your code trials?

Comment: @DebanjanB I updated the question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. Also [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481)

Comment: @DebanjanB Made another edit.

Answer (score 1):

Using cookies solved my issue

```java
public HomePage googleAutoLogin(String cookieKey, String cookieValue) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    Date afterOneHour = cal.getTime();

    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

    Cookie cookie = new Cookie.Builder(cookieKey, cookieValue)
            .domain("qreflect.com")
            .path("/")
            .expiresOn(afterOneHour)
            .isHttpOnly(true)
            .build();

    driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
    driver.navigate().refresh();
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Finished adding cookie");

    return this;
}
```

you have to login manually once then inspect to get cookies related to your app session, store them somewhere and pass the key/value pair to this method to get logged in.